# Calculate retention or return rate in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in big query and there are two columns on which I want to perform retention:-

```
Date                           user
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-04 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-05 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-10 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-13 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-18 08:35:07 UTC        foo3@abc.com
2021-02-21 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-23 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-24 08:35:07 UTC        foo5@abc.com
2021-02-24 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
```

I want to calculate daily retention here. the total number of unique players playing on the first day also played on the second and third and so on the day.

Suppose a game is installed on day 0 and on day 0 if 10 unique users played and on day 1 if 4 of them played then the retention on day 1 is 40% and so on.

So, I want to calculate the retention from day 1 to date.

The output will be:-

```
Day1  Day2  Day3........DayN
40%   50%   30%         70%
```

Comment: Why is there a `mysql` tag?

Comment: because even a MySQL answer will help..

Comment: Check out [intersect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#intersect_example)

Comment: My data is in one table but thanks!

Comment: Mysql ang bigquery syntax and functionality are different. If you are using bigquery, let's stick to that. Sergey's answer below, as an example, would not run on mysql.

Comment: Try `sql` tag to increase visibility

Comment: Thaks did that!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate retention between day 0 and day 1 you can use `intersect`:

```
select 
  ( select count(*)
    from (
      select user from mytable where date >= '2021-02-03 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-04 00:00:00'
      intersect distinct
      select user from mytable where date >= '2021-02-04 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-05 00:00:00'
    )
  ) / count(distinct user)
from mytable where date >= '2021-02-03 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-04 00:00:00'
```

To calculate retention between day 0 and day 2:

```
select 
  ( select count(*)
    from (
      select user from mytable where date >= '2021-02-03 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-04 00:00:00'
      intersect distinct
      select user from mytable where date >= '2021-02-05 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-06 00:00:00'
    )
  ) / count(distinct user)
from mytable where date >= '2021-02-03 00:00:00' and date < '2021-02-04 00:00:00'
```

Comment: So, I have to write 10 queries if I want to calculate retention between day 0 and day 10???